# What is the benefit of ASP.NET bundling and minification in runtime?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, bundling-and-minification

I understand how to use asp.net's new bundling and minification features. They are helpful during development.

Is there any benefit to using them in a production deployment though?  Would the system perform better if you just placed the bundled/minified files on the web server? It seems that overall, less code would run if they were just static files.

Note: I understand the benefit of having js/css bundled and minified. I am only questioning the value of using an active runtime process to generate those files in a production system as opposed to simply storing them on disk and referencing them as static files.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Bundling and Minification is more useful in production than in development.
It  can significantly improve your first page hit download time.

- Bundling reduces the number of individual HTTP requests to server by combining multiple CSS files and Javascript files into single CSS file and javascript file.
- Minification reduces the file download size of CSS and javascript files by removing whitespace, comments and other unnecessary characters.

Such small advantages are more pronounced in a production environment than in development. So it is better to go with Bundling and Minification in production.

Specific to your question there is no palpable benefit in bundling/minification during runtime. This feature is there just to make the developer's work easier. So it is even better to go with manually bundled/minified assets in production if you are sure about what you are doing.

**Update:**
According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vs11trainingcourse_aspnetandvisualstudio_topic5.aspx) there is a real benefit in bundling/minification during runtime

> Bundling and minification in ASP.NET 4.5 is performed at runtime, so that the process can identify the user agent (for example IE, Mozilla, etc.), and thus, improve the compression by targeting the user browser (for instance, removing stuff that is Mozilla specific when the request comes from IE).`
>
> The power of dynamic bundling is that you can include static JavaScript, as well as other files in languages that compiles into JavaScript.`

For example, CoffeeScript is a programming language that compiles into JavaScript

Comment: If you're going to copy and paste a section of text from somewhere else, please include a link to the source.

Comment: Sorry, I must not have been clear enough. I'll edit the question to be more clear.  I understand the benefit of using bundled/minified files. I just am questioning whether we need to use the bundling and minification process in production. Why not just use the bundled/minified assets?

Comment: Folks, this does not answer the question. The question was about why you would generate the bundled/minified files in production as opposed to deploying them as static.

Comment: Thanks, that's kind of what I am thinking. Benefits at design time but not so much at runtime.

Comment: the version hash string added to the resource url is another benefit. I guess you could manually do that too...but then you could do a lot manually in the name of optimization

Answer (score 2):

Bundling and minification provide 2 basic functionality in order to improve the performance of page load.

**Bundling** - Bundle all the provided scripts/ CSS in one file so that only browser need to load one file instead of multiple.
**Note->** Generally browsers can may only 6 simultaneous requests to get resources from the server. Additional requests are queued by the browser for later processing. Hence, if we have multiple files then it may have to wait in the request queue.

**Minification** - Minification process generates a minified file by removing comments, extra white spaces and renames the variable names. So this reduces the file size and results in faster download.

Comment: The question was not about bundling/minification but about whether the doing the process of budling/minifying at runtime on a production server made sense rather than just deploying the bundled/minified files as part of your deployment process.

Answer (score 1):

Minification- smaller files, less kb on the wire, faster page load.

Bundling- browsers limit connection per http host. This means that a user goes to your page, and you have (let's say) 24 script and link (css) tags, your browser is handling them 6 (most browser's limitation) at a time - slowing the page load.
Bundling makes the browser treat all your files a single file - overriding this limitation.

Comment: This does not answer the question. The question was about why you would generate the bundled/minified files in production as opposed to deploying them as static.

Comment: As for the real question, I don't see the benefit of the deploying static files. With proper caching strategy, even if your app needs to generate the files, it will generate them once. On the other hand, if you use static files you added another (redundant, if i may say so) to your deployment plan.

Comment: Didn't know about the 6 at a time limitation. Kudos

Answer (score 1):

Another benefit of bundling is it reduces caching issues. When we use bundling its loading to the page with a key, like below.

```
<script src="/bundles/jquery?v=FVs3ACwOLIVInrAl5sdzR2jrCDmVOWFbZMY6g6Q0ulE1"></script>
```

Each time we change our scripts it generates different key. So the file will be cached if we change something. But when we don't use this since script file has the same name, sometimes we have to clear cache to see the change.