# What are the cost/benefits of bundling a single file in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, bundle

I am creating a website using asp.net mvc5 and I need to add one particular css and js file to a single page. My question is, what would be the benefit of creating a new bundle for a single css or js file? Or is bundling a single file bad practice, and I shouldn't do it?

The code below is what I mean by not bundling vs bundling a single file:

```
Traditional Method:
<link href="/content/css/foo.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="~/content/js/bar.min.js"></script>

Bundle Method:
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bar").Include(
    "~/content/js/bar.min.js"));

bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/content/foobundle").Include(
     "~/content/css/foo.css"));
```

This question is in reference to bundling single files only. Like in my case, I am using a date-picker plugin that is only being used on one page in my ASP.NET MVC application, so it does not make sense to add the css and js files to my entire website bundle.

Comment: You'll have to measure it.

Comment: You also get versioning when using bundling (e.g. <script src="~/bundles/bar?v=?v=wBEWDufH_8Md-Pbioxomt90vm6tJN2Pyy9u9zHtWsPo1"></script>) which might be of value

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, bundling is a once-and-done thing, so I wouldn't focus much on the performance cost of bundling. In other words, the first time the bundle is requested, it must be created, but each subsequent request just statically serves up the previously created file (assuming you don't change the bundle).

Is there value in bundling a single file? Well, that depends on that single file. How large is it? Is it already minimized? If it's a large, unminimized file then yes, there's very much value in bundling it as the bundle version will be a smaller filesize. It's more obvious of course with multiple files, as there you're not only reducing file size but also requests. However, I would still recommend that you always just use bundles. Like I said above, the cost of bundling is occurred only on the first request, which if you're truly concerned about it, could always be requested by *you* after you publish the site. Then, each further request is statically served until you change the bundle.

Comment: Well said. I would add that you can also do the bundling and minification at runtime [through other tools](http://www.jeffreyfritz.com/2015/05/where-did-my-asp-net-bundles-go-in-asp-net-5/), some of which are already integrated into VS. Then you avoid the "first request" issue.

Comment: Hey great answer! Thank you for taking the time to explain how bundling works in ASP.NET. Being new to bundles, I wasn't sure how it affected load times, but that made a lot of sense. And thank you for addressing the single file question. I will always use bundles. :)

Answer (score 0):

Its a valuable feature and much more valuable on a production environment. That being said, on the projects I'm on - we use the feature regardless of the number of files.

This SO answer is really good:

[What is the benefit of ASP.NET bundling and minification in runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12804955/what-is-the-benefit-of-asp-net-bundling-and-minification-in-runtime)

Comment: If you think it's a duplicate, then flag it or vote to close. Right now, your answer doesn't really stand on its own.

Comment: Thanks for the reply and link. So just to clarify, even in the cases of a single file, you would still create the bundle for it?

Comment: Do you anticipate more files? If so, then yes.

Comment: What if you don't anticipate more files? Like you want to load a certain plugin that is only used on one web page. So I assume it doesn't make sense to add it to your entire website bundle, but only load the css and js files on the page it is being used on.

Comment: @Wellspring Nobody else can answer that for you. At some point, you need to make your own decisions for your apps.

Comment: @mason My answer reflects my professional opinion and Wellspring was essentially asking for an opinion. I feel that I gave an appropriate answer and credit to another SO post which had specifics. But sure, flag it as a duplicate if you want.

Comment: @Wellspring mason is correct. It boils down to your requirements and what you feel is the most appropriate design. Though, I personally try to follow best practices.

Comment: If someone is "essentially asking for an opinion" then the question should probably be flagged as "primarily opinion based". Your entire answer boiled down to "yes, we do that". But that doesn't make for a valuable answer. And the problem with saying "follow best practice" is *who* decides what is best practice?

Comment: @mason Duly noted. I'll consider your feedback the next time I am thinking of responding to a question / post.