# Single page application performance issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs

We are Developing Single page web application with angular js.Our problem is as we navigate through different URLS more and more java script has been added to browser memory so making application gradually slow.Is there any way to improve performance of such single page application when your app is going to increase in size?

Comment: Try using Angular's ui-router for routing.

Comment: you can bundle the javascript. It actually reduces http call everytime. Refer [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12804955/what-is-the-benefit-of-asp-net-bundling-and-minification-in-runtime)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should include all of your JavaScript files into one file to reduce network I/O. There are tools out there which do this, just google "JavaScript concat".

You can take it one step further and minify/uglify your JavaScript.

Add your JavaScript file to the main index.html file. You should not be re-loading it within your views.

If you still have performance issues then there is a bigger issue at hand.

Comment: Be wary about using this technique, as increasing your javascript payload can drastically increase dev code iteration time with some setups.

Answer (score 1):

Best way is to load your js files only when you needs that. Lazy loading is the method. Initially load only the main js files and **before moving to another `url`, `lazy load` the required js files**.

`oc.lazyLoad` is a good solution for your problem.

download `oc.lazyLoad` and inject that dependency to your app like

`var myApp = angular.module("MyApp", ["oc.lazyLoad"]);`

and you have a js file named `testModule.js` and you know where is the use of that file. So before goto that URL, load your js file like

```
myApp.controller("MyCtrl", function($ocLazyLoad) {
  $ocLazyLoad.load('testModule.js');
});
```

for more clarity and information [Read here](https://oclazyload.readme.io/docs)

Answer (score 0):

Check for memory leak :

- remove $rootScope listener, $timeout, $interval, $watch on directive or controller destroy.
- remove event listener on directive destroy.

And if it's really slow, try to use fewer watch, use one time binding, use track by on ng-repeat. But still if you have memory issue, you will have to track what's increasing it anyway.

And if you want easy performance boost, don't forget to add this in your app config when you go in production :

```
$compileProvider.debugInfoEnabled(false);
```