# Which way of referencing libraries is faster ?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Can somebody tell me In ASP.NET MVC Projects when referencing Jquery and css libraries which way is faster ? referencing the urls like below or adding to bundle config ?

```
<head>
<link href="~/Content/themes/base/datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">


<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Thank You

Comment: If you have a performance question, why not measure and try it yourself?

Comment: check performance using bundiling

Comment: Just to make sure is there is accepted way of doing. may be like these libraries here and these type of libraries better be like this and like so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good answer this question can be found on [this semi-related question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12804955/what-is-the-benefit-of-asp-net-bundling-and-minification-in-runtime)

Bundling and minification combines multiple JavaScript files and CSS files to reduce requests and bytes transferred, which decreases load times.

By using bundling and minification for multiple libraries, you can decrease your initial page load time on a production server, according to [this article - "Performance Implications of Bundling and Minification on Web Browsing" by Henrik F Nielsen:](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/henrikn/2012/06/16/performance-implications-of-bundling-and-minification-on-web-browsing/)

> The data analyzed shows that bundling and minification can result in
>   significant savings in terms of bytes exchanged and requests executed
>   and hence lead to faster page render times. Further, by adding
>   compression and pipelining it is possible to get significant speedup
>   in the time it takes to download the HTML, CSS and JS for laying out a
>   page, especially by putting the links to the bundled and minified CSS
>   and JS at the very top of the HTML.

According to the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vs11trainingcourse_aspnetandvisualstudio_topic5.aspx),

> The new bundling feature in ASP.NET 4.5 packs a set of JS or CSS files
>   into a single element, and reduces its size by minifying the content
>   (i.e. removing not required blank spaces, removing comments, reducing
>   identifiers).
>
> Bundling and minification in ASP.NET 4.5 is performed at runtime, so
>   that the process can identify the user agent (for example IE, Mozilla,
>   etc.), and thus, improve the compression by targeting the user browser
>   (for instance, removing stuff that is Mozilla specific when the
>   request comes from IE).

The MSDN also provides examples of how to perform bundling in Visual Studio on ASP.NET 4.5.

In short, bundling & minification is faster in a production environment. Because of the benefits in a production environment, you should probably do it, regardless of any arguable benefits in a development environment.